# /index.php/news - что это?

Tags: php, apache

допустимы ли ссылки такого типа:

````
/index.php/online-shop
/index.php/custom-parts
/index.php/umbauten```
````

Comment: Почему бы и нет?

Comment: По сути, допустимы ссылки любого вида. Другое дело уже как вы их будете обрабатывать.

Comment: эти ссылки состоят только из относительного пути или включают в себя запрос?

Comment: добавт тег а и попробуй перейти

Comment: Часть URL после имени файла попадает в `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка - это просто идентификатор. Он может содержать в себе любые допустимые символы. К примеру, ссылка может быть и такой `index.php/blog.php/article.php/show/1`
Такие ссылки обрабатываются сервером и скриптами. Физически файлы могут не существовать.